# error to inserting from textbox.getText() to my model in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I use retrofit2 in Android.

I create `UserModel` and `AuthModel` and call method from my activity to the server ;

**UserModel.class**

```
public class UserModel {
    public  String  fullName;
    public String about;
    public String userName;
    public String password;
    public Date createDate;
    public Date lastSeen;
    public String phonenumber; 
    ...
}
```

**AothModel.class**

```
public class AuthModel {
    public UserModel user;
    public TokenModel token;
    public ErrorResponseModel errorResponse;
    ...
}
```

**And my Activity**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_singup);

        edtPhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtphone);
        AuthModel authModel = new AuthModel();
        authModel.user.phonenumber = edtPhone.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(SingUpActivity.this,authModel.user.phonenumber,
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I set text in `UserModel.phonenumber` model variable and test it.
Error:

> Attempt to write to field `'java.lang.String com.mychat.models.UserModel.phonenumber'` on a `null` object reference

Comment: authModel.user is null. Instantiate it by writing authModel.user = new UserModel(); and then assign the phonenumber

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because you didn't create `UserModel`instance in the `AuthModel`. You initialized `AuthModel` but it won't automatically create `UserModel` instance. That's why it throws NullPointerException whenever you try to access to any properties in `UserModel`, because it is just `null`.

Change your code like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_singup);
        edtPhone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtphone);
        AuthModel authModel=new AuthModel();
        UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
        authModel.setUserModel(userModel);
        authModel.user.phonenumber = edtPhone.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(SingUpActivity.this,authModel.user.phonenumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or you can just create a constructor in AuthModel that accepts a new UserModel as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialize `user` variable of `AuthModel` model

So `user` is `null` and it giving error

```
'java.lang.String com.mychat.models.UserModel.phonenumber' on a null object reference
```

Modify your code and init `user` variable of `authModel`

```
AuthModel authModel = new AuthModel();
UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
authModel.user = userModel;
authModel.user.phonenumber = edtPhone.getText().toString();
```